# sw-precache, cache files with URL Parameters

Tags: service-worker, polymer-2.x, polymer-cli, sw-precache

I have a quick question.

I'm building a PWA with Polymer and **Lighthouse** reports, that the manifest's `start_url` is not cached by the **ServiceWorker**.

Since I want to track the users, which use the 'Add to homescreen' function, my manifest.json contains

`"start_url": "index.html?homescreen=1",`

I tried putting this exact string into my `sw-precache` config file, but the script generates a ServiceWorker, that just caches the index.html file.
 (I'm aware, that it's a bit redundant to cache index.html & index.html?homescreen=1)

Do you have any idea, how to fix this behaviour?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ignoreUrlParametersMatching` option](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#ignoreurlparametersmatching-arrayregex) is `sw-precache` can help you here.

By default, it's set to `[/^utm_/]`, meaning that if you configured your Web App Manifest like

```
{
  "start_url": "index.html?utm_source=homescreen"
}
```

then things should work as expected. If you'd like to keep that `?homescreen=1`, then, when generating your service worker, you can change explicitly set the `ignoreUrlParametersMatching` parameter to `[/^homescreen/]`.

Comment: That was a very good answer! 
Do you have an idea, how to cache routes, like `start_url: '/about?utm_source=homescreen` which would resolve in a view file located at `/src/views/about-view.html` ?

Comment: No, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Is it possible to add such rule to an app created with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) boilerplate without eject?

Comment: c-r-a uses `sw-precache` under the hood, and it will automatically precache any local HTML files at build time. So if you have a local about.html file, that will work as expected without ejecting.